# FQL doesn't return mobile photos groups uploaded via the Facebook Camera app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, mobile, upload, camera, facebook-fql

It looks like the FQL query to return photos from a user's Mobile Uploads album doesn't return all of a user's uploaded the photos. This is the case for any photo groups (when uploading more than 1 photo at a time) from the Facebook Camera app. These photos get grouped into their own data entity, and do not get returned when I query for all photos from Mobile Uploads via FQL. However, if I do the same query but via the Graph Api, all those photos do get returned, so it looks like there's an inconsistency between the way the Graph Api returns the photos data and the way FQL returns it. The Graph Api seems to return a more comprehensive set of results.

Comment: ** update: it looks like there is no difference between the fql and graph api results, it's only a matter of different levels of access tokens. The access token retrieved at the facebook.com level returns all results, but the access token retrieved at the app level doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that if you upload multiple photos they gets categorised as a status update and you need the user's "user_status" permission to access them through the API, even though they're in the mobile uploads album (any other photo in there you can access with only the user_photos permission)